# Como montar um array de mensagem e enviar num BadRequest

Tags: c#

Entendi no post anterior o badrequest. Eu preciso montar uma mensagem para ele da seguinte forma. Caso uma mercadoria não possua um Serial Number, devo montar uma mensagem e enviar. Digamos que minha query me retorne 7 itens e desses dois não possuem Serial Number. Esses dois deverão compor a mensagem do BadRequest. Tipo assim:

```
if(Num.SerialNumber == nul)
{
  //aqui vai a mensagem. Veja que é um array, pois tenho dois caras sem o SN
}
```

aí sim, no result da minha Action faço

```
return BadRequest(mensagem);
```

onde mensagem seria os caras sem o SN.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando `WebApi` pode retornar uma lista de objetos, segue exemplo:

**Classe:**

```
    public class Aparelho
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SN { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MyEndPoint")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyEndPoint()
    {

        List<Aparelho> aparelhos = new List<Aparelho>
        {
            new Aparelho{ID=1, SN= null, Nome= "Aparelho 1"},
            new Aparelho{ID=2, SN= null, Nome= "Aparelho 2"},
            new Aparelho{ID=3, SN= null, Nome= "Aparelho 3"},
        };

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, aparelhos);
    }
```